# If rvalues did not bind to const references, how would this affect move semantics and perfect forwarding?

Tags: c++, c++11

In http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/1nl9at/i_am_a_member_of_facebooks_hhvm_team_a_c_and_d/ccjm2qs, Andrei Alexandrescu writes:

> I think binding rvalues to const references has been the small mistake
>   that caused the rvalue references Hindenburg... It would be a long
>   discussion. Binding rvalues to const& made sense when first introduced
>   (no templates, few subtleties) but in the long term made it virtually
>   impossible to distinguish rvalues from lvalues on the callee side.
>   That in turn forced an overly complex solution (rvalue references) as
>   an expensive fix.

If the choice had not been made to bind rvalues to const references, how would this affect move semantics and perfect forwarding?

Comment: That is Andrei Alexandrescu'sm opinion. So how can *we* backup his claim? If it is general community opinion, then we might backup, but it is an individual's opinion who often have different opinions on many things, such as iterators, well accepted by C++ experts.

Comment: We don't need to distinguish on the callee side. It passes as constant reference and supposed to be only `readable`, not `writable`. And rvalue reference is not `overly complex`.

Comment: I've reworded the question to make it factual rather than opinion based.

Comment: If rvalues do not bind to const references, what do they bind to?  Nothing?  non-`const` references?  Instances only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wasn't going to touch this question, considering it an extremely hypothetical question with not much value in answering.  But I've changed my mind.  There **is** value in answering this question that I did not previously comprehend.

Consider the common (not in C++, but in computer languages in general) API to split a string into an array of strings based on one or more delimiters.  This ideally would return "string views" or "string_refs" into the original string to avoid copying pieces of the original string.  A "string view" or "string_ref" is nothing but a pair of iterators into the original string.  So something like:

```
vector<string_ref> split(const string& str, const string& delim);
```

With it known that `vector<string_ref>` refers back into `str`, it would be a bad idea for this function to bind to an rvalue.  Once the client gets around to using the result, the reference into the argument would be long gone.  The references would be dangling.

Thus it would be a good idea to forbid this function from accepting rvalue arguments for `str`, even though it is not going to modify this argument.

That being said, we have **decades** of experience that strongly indicate that this example is **not** typical.  Most of the time, if a function isn't going to modify an argument, it does not matter if that argument is an rvalue or lvalue.

So if we had a clean sheet, it would make sense to make the common case be the easiest one to handle:  rvalues can bind to `const X&`.  But for cases like `split`, we need syntax for disallowing this common default behavior.  How 'bout:

```
vector<string_ref> split(const string& str, const string& delim);
vector<string_ref> split(const string&& str, const string& delim) = delete;
```

I'm having trouble coming up with anything more elegant than this.

In other words: Usually, with the benefit of 20/20 hindsight, and lack of backwards compatibility constraints, one can do better with a redesign, given a clean sheet.  But in this case, I've hypothesized myself a clean sheet, and I'm having trouble coming up with a better design than what we have.

`<Disclaimer>`
I'm biased.
`</Disclaimer>`

Comment: I’ve worked on a project that ran into exactly this problem. We essentially decided to document the behaviour and make it the user’s responsibility to ensure that the viewable object wasn’t a temporary (or otherwise went out of scope). Not great of course.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Could you enforce your policy with an overloaded deleted function as demonstrated in this answer?  (assuming your compiler implemented C++11).

Comment: That was way before C++11. The `delete`d function would of course work but only prevents use of temporaries, not other cases where a view outlives its host object.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: I'm guessing that the other cases would not be prevented whether temporaries (rvalues) would bind to const lvalue references or not (the premise of the OP's question).

Comment: @Howard, do you remember what this simpler scheme was? http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1622265 "I followed the rvalue proposal for C++ quite closely, and at one point I suggested a simpler scheme that Howard Hinnant proved to me would have broken compatibility (which is a no-no)."

Comment: @Jon:  I'm sorry, I don't recall the issue here.  If you have a more specific pointer I will try again.